# Separating words from a string using indexOf & substring methods in Java

Tags: java, string, substring, indexof, separator

Yo, I'm trying to write a program in Java that separates words from a string, using only substring and indexOf. I've already made this code and it runs almost perfect but it prints alot of empty line after printing the words.

```
class wordSep{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String line = "The world is full of strangers";
        String word = line.substring(0,line.indexOf(" "));
        int index = line.length()-1;
        while(index>=0){
            System.out.println(word);
            line = line.substring(line.indexOf(" ") + 1) + " ";
            word = line.substring(0,line.indexOf(" "));
            index--;
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this will be:

```
The
world
is
full
of
strangers
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
\\empty line
```

I think this has to do with the condition of my while loop. I need to have an output without those empty lines.. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace  `while(index>=0)` with `while(!word.isEmpty())` and get rid of `index`

Comment: Sorry I just created this account minutes ago, how do I vote up? Edit: lol it seems like I already voted up, what a noob.

Comment: @patmarley someone else has voted this answer, you need some reputations in order to vote up. Take a look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: @Jean - If I was asked not to use .isEmpty(), what other condition can I use for my while statement?

Answer (score 1):

That's great that your problem is solved but it would be great if you try to use some built in functions(like **String.split()**) and libraries in your code as it can reduce a lot of processing and make your code more robust and independent of String length and other parameters.

Your code could be optimized to this level...

```
 class wordSep{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String line = "The world is full of strangers";
        String[] word = line.split(" ");
        for(String str: word){
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

**output -**

```
The
world
is
full
of
strangers
```

Now you can also use String Tokenizer But it is not recommended any more...

**Read this ->  [to completely understand how to split Strings in Java on    some character, or using some Regex and other parameters](http://www.codingeek.com/java/methods-to-split-or-tokenize-string-into-its-components/)**

Comment: I've seen your solution even before posting this question, and if yours is applicable, I won't be asking this problem. Mine requires to split string without using split and an array. Thanks, read the title carefully next time. Peace!

Comment: I am sorry for that. I thought that you got a solution already so I must suggest something different to you.
So for just an improvement, in case you did not hardcode your String then there are chances of getting `nullPointerException` you can see how to avoid this in example in the link below. Although it uses some extra lines but lines are less important than the stability of code....

http://ideone.com/x7Tdks

Thanks for your suggestion....

Answer (score 0):

J. Lucky, you can reduce the number of sop's and the size as well, like this:

```
class Extract
{
    void Substring()
    {    
        String s = "The World is Full of Strangers.";
        s = s + " "; 
        int idxOfNextWord = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) 
        {
            if(s.charAt(i)== ' ') 
            {
                System.out.println(s.substring(idxOfNextWord, i));
                idxOfNextWord = i+1;
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Even though you seemed to have fixed the problem, still going to post this answer. I believe your code can be minimized into just a few lines like this:

```
String line = "The world is full of strangers";
int idxOfNextWord = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
    if(line.charAt(i)==' ') {
        System.out.println(line.substring(idxOfNextWord, i));
        idxOfNextWord = i+1;
    }            
}
System.out.println(line.substring(idxOfNextWord));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great having few lines and I appreciate it.

Comment: This does not take into account the last word.

Comment: @AdamArold, yes it does. That's the purpose of the last SOP.